# How to set VisualSVN Server master-slave (mirror) configuration on windows machines

Tags: svn, master-slave, visualsvn-server, mirror

We have three SVN Server on windows machine. One onsite (ON1) and two offshore (OF1, OF2).
I want to make the onsite SVN Repository as Master and offshore machines as mirrors.

User will commit to Offshore svn servers(any of OF1, OF2) which internally will get committed to Onsite server(ON1) and which will be SVNSYNCd to all slave servers (OF1 & OF2).

I am unable to understand the processes mentioned in various websites including svnbook.red-bean.com. Can anyone help me with a step by step approach to set this up. I am aware of httpd.conf and various svn hooks but in bits and pieces only.

Thanks.

Comment: "internally will get committed" you mean some other way than svnsync?

Comment: I guess by mod_rewrite but I am not sure.

Comment: If you configure the [write-through proxy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.writethruproxy) on the slave machines, the commit will get handed up to the master, committed, then replicated to the slaves via svnsync.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Multisite Repository Replication feature](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/multisite-replication/) or [configure write-through proxy](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/httpd/#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.writethruproxy).

Comment: Thanks. I posted it when I was on working on SVN and Java. Now moved to .net and TFS. I still appreciate it. This will definitely help others.